# I am trying to use three tables with one table that is holding the foregin keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am trying to get this SQL to work. Can anyone help me?

```
CREATE TABLE artists 
(
    a_id INTEGER , 
    namn TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tracks 
(
    t_id INTEGER ,
    titel   TEXT 
);

INSERT INTO artiststracks VALUES (2,2);

CREATE TABLE artiststracks 
(
    artist INTEGER,
    tracks INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(artist) REFERENCES artists(a_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(tracks) REFERENCES tracks(t_id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to `INSERT` into the last table named `artiststracks` you will be creating before it gets created. This is one place that will be an error. Re-arranging the code sequence should fix it -

```
CREATE TABLE artists (
  a_id INTEGER, 
  namn TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tracks (
  t_id INTEGER,
  titel TEXT 
);

CREATE TABLE artiststracks (
  artist INTEGER,
  tracks INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(artist) REFERENCES artists(a_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(tracks) REFERENCES tracks(t_id)
);

INSERT INTO artiststracks VALUES (2,2);
```